# What is a getty?

Tags: linux, terminal

What is a getty?

Some info here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Getty

It seems to be related to terminal, but what is the difference of getty and terminal? Archlinux by default boots into getty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

getty is a type of **tty** and a tty is your text input/output environment

Please see this answer on Unix & Linux StackExchange: [What is the exact difference between a terminal, a shell, a tty, and a console](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con)

I hope that helps.

---

Answer (score 1):

getty is a process that sets up the terminal and terminal/shell is an interpreter that takes input  from the user and displays the output for that command command.